# Loopback 4 authentication Issue with login controller

Tags: loopback4

I am trying to add authentication to my app. There are two models named user and user-credential. The user has one user-credential.

The post request to the User is working fine. Password is stored in the user-credential model(hashed) and other fields are stored in the user model.

But When I make login request I am getting following error

> Unhandled error in POST /users/login: 500 TypeError:
>   this.userRepository.findCredentials is not a function
>       at MyUserService.verifyCredentials (D:\ionic-pr\loopback-projects\no\node_modules@loopback\authentication-jwt\src\services\user.service.ts:38:56)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

The user-service inside authentication-jwt in node-modules is throwing error.

I can't get what is going wrong.

Thank you in advance

**EDIT:**  Now I have made two controllers. The first one makes post request works fine. And the second one performs login as below

imports  -

```
import {TokenService} from '@loopback/authentication';
import {Credentials, MyUserService, TokenServiceBindings, UserRepository, UserServiceBindings} from "@loopback/authentication-jwt";
import {inject} from '@loopback/core';
import {repository} from '@loopback/repository';
import {post, requestBody} from '@loopback/rest';
import {SecurityBindings, UserProfile} from '@loopback/security';
```

constructor -

```
constructor(
    @inject(TokenServiceBindings.TOKEN_SERVICE)
    public jwtService: TokenService,
    @inject(UserServiceBindings.USER_SERVICE)
    public userService: MyUserService,
    @inject(SecurityBindings.USER, {optional: true})
    public user: UserProfile,
    @repository(UserRepository) protected userRepository: UserRepository,
  )
```

Comment: `.verifyCredentials()` is calling `.findCredentials()`, which the error says it's not a function. However, that part of the code is not posted in your question.

Comment: It is written in npm package @loopback/authentication-jwt. I have used the same. User service can be found here https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/master/extensions/authentication-jwt/src/services/user.service.ts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you stated you are using @ loopback/authenntication-jwt

```
import {User} from '../models';
import {UserRepository} from '../repositories';
```

From above it seems that you have created your own user-repository. You are not usng the default one from the extension, which is throwing error.
the above import should be like

```
import {
  Credentials,
  MyUserService,
  TokenServiceBindings,
  User,
  UserRepository,
  UserServiceBindings,
} from "@loopback/authentication-jwt";
```

This will fix you out. 
If you are trying to create your own custom user than please refer https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/tree/master/extensions/authentication-jwt#customizing-user
Also you have imported wrong UserSerivce. it should be from @loopback/authentication-jwt
and your injection should be like

@inject(UserServiceBindings.USER_SERVICE) public userService: MyUserService,

Comment: Thank you for cooperation @Yashpal Singh Kadam.  Can you please find edited question and tell me what is wrong. Thank you

Comment: can you push your code to git. so that we would get what you are exactly catching.

Comment: Actually I was using my repository for post signup and using loopback-jiw's repository for login. That is the reason it was not working, Thank you for offering help.

Comment: If you can look at this, it would be great help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61969175/loopback-4-authentication-error-while-binding-custom-service

Comment: @Madaky Hey! Life saver... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If some people have similar issue and the above solution is already what you us it might simply be that there is a conflict with a `UserRepository` defined in your code.

Indeed `UserServiceBindings.USER_SERVICE` will load a `UserRepository`. If you defined in your project a `UserRepository` class this can create a conflict and make the injection inject your `UserRepository` instead of the one from `authentication-jwt`. You can see this by logging `this.userRepository`.

The solution is simple : rename your local `UserRepository` class by something else.

> Note : this does not seem to be an issue with a custom `User` class.