# Loopback 4 authentication error while binding custom service

Tags: loopback4

I have followed this [link](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/tree/master/extensions/authentication-jwt#customizing-user) for creating custom service for authentication in loopback 4. I successfully created the service but while binding this service in application.ts I am getting the following error.

> Argument of type 'typeof CustomUserService' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type 'Constructor>'.
>   Construct signature return types 'CustomUserService' and
>   'UserService' are incompatible.
>       The types returned by 'verifyCredentials(...)' are incompatible between these types.
>         Type 'Promise'
>   is not assignable to type
>   'Promise'.
>           Property 'userCredentials' is missing in type 'import("d:/ionic-pr/loopback-projects/custom/src/models/user.model").User'
>   but required in type
>   'import("d:/ionic-pr/loopback-projects/custom/node_modules/@loopback/authentication-jwt/dist/models/user.model").User'

**GIT REPOSITORY** - https://github.com/pratikjaiswal15/loopbck4uth

I have two models user and userCred with has one realtionship.  The relation name is `userCred`.

here is the code

thank you in advance

application.ts

```
import {UserCredRepository, UserRepository} from './repositories';
import {CustomUserService} from './services/custom-user.service';
import {UserServiceBindings} from '@loopback/authentication-jwt';

// Bind user service inside constructor
    this.bind(UserServiceBindings.USER_SERVICE).toClass(CustomUserService),// error on this line

      // Bind user and credentials repository
      this.bind(UserServiceBindings.USER_REPOSITORY).toClass(
        UserRepository,
      ),

      this.bind(UserServiceBindings.USER_CREDENTIALS_REPOSITORY).toClass(
        UserCredRepository,
      )
```

custom-service.ts

```
import {UserService} from '@loopback/authentication';
import {repository} from '@loopback/repository';
import {HttpErrors} from '@loopback/rest';
import {securityId, UserProfile} from '@loopback/security';
import {compare} from 'bcryptjs';
// User --> MyUser
import {User} from '../models/user.model';
// UserRepository --> MyUserRepository
import {Credentials, UserRepository} from '../repositories/user.repository';


export class CustomUserService implements UserService<User, Credentials> {
  constructor(
    // UserRepository --> MyUserRepository
    @repository(UserRepository) public userRepository: UserRepository,
  ) {}

  // User --> MyUser
  async verifyCredentials(credentials: Credentials): Promise<User> {
    const invalidCredentialsError = 'Invalid email or password.';

    const foundUser = await this.userRepository.findOne({
      where: {email: credentials.email},
    });
    if (!foundUser) {
      throw new HttpErrors.Unauthorized(invalidCredentialsError);
    }

    const credentialsFound = await this.userRepository.findCredentials(
      foundUser.id,
    );
    if (!credentialsFound) {
      throw new HttpErrors.Unauthorized(invalidCredentialsError);
    }

    const passwordMatched = await compare(
      credentials.password,
      credentialsFound.password,
    );

    if (!passwordMatched) {
      throw new HttpErrors.Unauthorized(invalidCredentialsError);
    }

    return foundUser;
  }

  // User --> MyUser
  convertToUserProfile(user: User): UserProfile {

    let address = ''
    if (user.address) {
      address = user.address
    }

    return {
      [securityId]: user.id!.toString(),
      name: user.name,
      id: user.id,
      email: user.email,
      address: address

    };


  }
}
```

user.repositor.ts

```
import {Getter, inject} from '@loopback/core';
import {DefaultCrudRepository, HasOneRepositoryFactory, repository} from '@loopback/repository';
import {MygodDataSource} from '../datasources';
import {User, UserCred, UserRelations} from '../models';
import {UserCredRepository} from './user-cred.repository';

export type Credentials = {
  email: string;
  password: string;
};



export class UserRepository extends DefaultCrudRepository<
  User,
  typeof User.prototype.id,
  UserRelations
  > {

  public readonly userCred: HasOneRepositoryFactory<UserCred, typeof User.prototype.id>;

  constructor(
    @inject('datasources.mygod') dataSource: MygodDataSource, @repository.getter('UserCredRepository') protected userCredRepositoryGetter: Getter<UserCredRepository>,
  ) {
    super(User, dataSource);
    this.userCred = this.createHasOneRepositoryFactoryFor('userCred', userCredRepositoryGetter);
    this.registerInclusionResolver('userCred', this.userCred.inclusionResolver);
  }


  async findCredentials(
    userId: typeof User.prototype.id,
  ): Promise<UserCred | undefined> {
    try {
      return await this.userCred(userId).get();
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.code === 'ENTITY_NOT_FOUND') {
        return undefined;
      }
      throw err;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please find git repository https://github.com/pratikjaiswal15/loopbck4uth

Answer (score 1):

have a brief explaination of the issue at your git post Follow you answer at 
https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/5541